# What are some types of topologically-relevant band degeneracies in contemporary 2D condensed matter research?

Tags: band-structure, one-topic-per-answer, condensed-matter, topological-insulators, berry-phase

In the study of 2D condensed matter systems, I have seen several kinds of band degeneracies. I call 'bands' the eigenvalues to the time-independent Schrodinger equation, solved over 2D k-space. By 'degenerate', I refer to when the eigenvalues to one eigenvector are the same as the eigenvalues of a different eigenvector at the same k-space point.

I have seen bands that are:

1. degenerate at certain high symmetry points (such as graphene);
2. 'fully gapped' (with no degeneracies whatsoever);
3. completely degenerate (such as the 4-band Kane-Mele model, where each pair of bands is degenerate everywhere over k-space);
4. degenerate at non-high-symmetry points (degenerate in such ways that make them    'accidental degeneracies'?)
5. degenerate at certain high symmetry areas (similar to 4., but also includes lines and patches of k-space)

#### My question is:

**Which of the above are relevant to topological effects (or coincide with those)?** I have seen 1-3 above pretty often, but am having trouble understanding 4 (and 5). You only need to list one to post an answer, see [one-topic-per-answer](/questions/tagged/one-topic-per-answer). If there's another type of degeneracy relevant to topological effects that I didn't list above, you can explain that one too.

---

Consider the attached picture, which is a random band diagram for $MoS_2$ that I found online. To my understanding, people do not care about degenercies of the kind I have circled in red (i.e. of type 4 in the list above). This is because they tend to care about the physics around the 'valleys' indicated by red arrows (i.e. fully gapped, no degeneracies). They usually do this by working with an effective Hamiltonian focusing on a subspace of the complete Hilbert space. Then, for topological reasons, they might treat the entire 'bundle' of wavefunctions above and below the Fermi level (indicated by red arrows), regardless of the degeneracies circled in red.

However, it seems suspicious to me that the 'degeneracies' circled are assumed to not play a role in topological properties. To paint a naive/vague picture, consider Haldane's interpretation of topologically significant degeneracies of a 2-level model as Dirac strings/wormholes that connect two otherwise-separate genus-1 tori into a genus-3 torus (second picture, taken from [these slides](https://physics.princeton.edu//%7Ehaldane/talks/dirac.pdf)). So, I am looking for consolation/clarification on why we can simply ignore degeneracies that occur outside the regions of interest, in general topological concerns. Or if anyone sees my overall confusion, I would appreciate any guiding remarks.

Note: I am more concerned about the type of 2D topology that deals with Berry-like quantities (Berry phase, curvature, Chern / valley Chern, etc).

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 But you seem to be asking 2 questions in 1 post which is usually discouraged: For the second question, are you only asking for examples *that are relevant to topological effects*? Then this could be acceptable as in the case where I wrote "any others you may wish to add" at the bottom of this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1594/5. But if you're asking for other types of degeneracies in general, maybe that could be left for a separate one-topic-per-answer question, in which each answer is a new type of degeneracy?

Comment: Cross posting (asking the same question on multiple sites) is discouraged because it makes it harder to see whether a question has already been answered on another site. You should either delete the question on one of the sites or include a link at the top of each post to the version of the question on the other site.

Comment: @NikeDattani I can see how it seems as if I am asking two questions. When asking, it felt like just one big question requesting extra clarification on a subset of the answer. If you have any recommendations on how to improve the question, please feel free to make them.

Comment: @Tyberius I just edited both questions to include a link. I posted on both platforms because when my bounty on the last question I asked expired, I was advised to ask Physics SE.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. When a question fits on both sites, I think it can be a good idea to have multiple posts, but it's just good practice to keep everyone aware of multiple posts to avoid duplicating effort.

Comment: @TribalChief About your question "are there more kinds of degeneracies not listed above?" Are you wondering only about ones that are relevant to topological effects? Or about more types of degeneracies in general?

Comment: @NikeDattani, I meant those relevant to topological effects. Sorry it wasn't clear.

Comment: @TribalChief Great, now it's just one question :) It can stay the way it is :)

Comment: +1 A few ideas: graphene also has doubly-degenerate bands everywhere (and the Dirac point is 4-fold degenerate). Any system with both inversion and time-reversal symmetry will have all bands doubly degenerate. As to the question about band crossings away from the Fermi level, they are usually physically irrelevant because you cannot access them -- you are typically limited to electrons within a few 100 meV of the Fermi level.

Comment: TribalChief, were the ideas by @ProfM helpful for you to get on the right track? If you have an answer now, it would be helpful to write a self-answer. Same if ProfM would like to expand the comment into an answer. This has now been in the unanswered queue for more than 6 months!

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks for checking in. I really am not sure. The answers to this question seem to be context-dependent (ex: 2D vs 3D). In 2D, people seem to consider topological effects away from the gap crossings in the picture. My guess is that 4) and 5) in my question may not be related to topological effects. Part of my motivation for these sub-parts question was the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338590/are-python-matlab-mathematica-numerical-eigenvectors-affected-by-eigenvalue-dege

Comment: I've upvoted that, but it looks like the [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/32416/tribalchief) community would be more likely to be able to give you an answer quickly. @Tyberius may know more since he's active there.

Comment: @Tyberius am I right about the CompSci.SE community being able to help with this type of question faster than us? I made that suggestion after seeing OP's reply to my last comment, which said "Part of my motivation for these sub-parts question was the following:" followed by an **unanswered** question on Math.SE which seems to me, might be faster answered on CompSci.SE.

Comment: @NikeDattani I'm not sure about this post, it I think at least the unanswered question on Math SE might work better on Comp Sci.

Comment: @Tyberius I've pinged Anton to take a look, and flagged the question on Math.SE to let them know that. If Anton agrees, the Math.SE question can be migrated to CompSci.SE. Maybe once TribalChief gets an answer to the Math.SE question (hopefully quickly, after migration to CompSci), then the path towards an answer to this question will become clearer. What do you think TribalChief? Shall we wait until you get an answer to the Math.SE question before devoting resources to try to answer this MMSE one?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP returns and addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.